# Properties in a module

Tags: properties, typescript, accessor

Is there a way to define a property in a TypeScript `module`?

None of these compile:

```
module My {
    // doesnt work
    get Value(): number { return 42; }

    // doesn't work either
    get function Value(): number { return 42; }

    // nope
    function get Value(): number { return 42; }
}
```

Right now I'm forced to use this:

```
module My {
    declare var Value: number;
    Object.defineProperty(My, "Value", {
        get: () => 42
    });
}
```

The second form seems messy to me and the code hinting doesn't really treat it as a read-only property but as a plain variable.

Is there any standard way of defining properties directly inside modules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's not a way to declare a property on a `module` in TypeScript using any documented language features.

You can do it in several slightly round-about techniques.

A `module` can extend an existing `class` or `function`. So, I've created a class with a `static` property, and then later created a `module` that uses the same name as the `class`.

```
class My
{
    static get Value():Number {
        return 42;
    }
}

module My {
    var works: boolean = true;
}

alert(My.Value);
```

It does generate one oddity in the JavaScript generated code that you wouldn't do manually (and should be removed by most optimizers anyway) ... it will redeclare the variable `My` when the module is created. This does not cause a run-time issue as the variable was already lifted in JavaScript and will not conflict with the first usage.

Here's another option:

```
module Global {
    class Inner {
        get Value():Number {
            return 42;
        }       
    }   
    export var My;
    My = new Inner();
}

var My = Global.My;
alert(My.Value);
```

While it presents an extra namespace, you can manipulate it however you'd like and use the inner class or change it as needed. This way, the `My` variable is global, just like it would be as a `module`.

Comment: This seems more hacky than what I'm currently using. Besides, the properties in the class have no access to 'private' variables/functions in the module which kinda defeats the purpose of most properties.

Comment: I wouldn't agree that it's more hacky, as this relies only on standard, supported TypeScript. I'd suggest you just export a class in the `My` module with the functionality you want on it. A TypeScript `module` shouldn't have properties (as it's not supported by the language). Edited question to include another option.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `module` keyword, consider instead using `export`, which will allow you to do what you want to do, treating the file itself as a module (which is how CommonJS and AMD both work).

```ts
// in My.ts
var My = {
  get value() {
    return 42;
  }
};

export = My;
```

```ts
// in foo.ts
import My = require('My');
console.log(My.value);
```

I describe this in greater detail in a blog post, [The Definitive Guide to TypeScript](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2013/12/31/definitive-guide-to-typescript/#imports-and-exports).

Comment: Well I actually use modules as modules... they may have inner classes, add event listeners and other such things, so substituting them for objects is either impossible or just very 'uncomfortable'.

Comment: You wouldn’t “substitute them for objects”; the root of the TypeScript file becomes the body of the module. At the end of whatever procedural code you run inside the module, then you export the value explicitly.

Comment: It most certainly is.

Comment: Please, do tell me exactly which part of the generated output is not valid EcmaScript 5 when running `tsc -t es5 -m amd My.ts`.

Comment: This response is from 2014.  Has it changed in 3 years (to the day)?

Comment: @Daryl Today you would want to use `export function value() { return 42; }` and create no `My` object at all on the producer side, and `import * as My from 'My';` (or just `import { value as getValue } from 'My';`) on the consumer side.

Comment: Kind of hard to read in the comments, could you add it as an update to your post?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the singleton

```
let My = {
  get value() {
    return 42;
  }
}

export My
```

but ran into an issue where the emitted JS still said `get value()` and didn't work on older versions of Node. I tried `Object.defineProperty` but then lost TypeScript compatibility. Here's my bridge that fixes both cases:

```
interface My {
  value: number
}

// type assertion fixes TypeScript usage
let my = <My>{}
// defineProperty fixes JS usage
Object.defineProperty(my, 'value', {
  get: () => 42
});

export = my;
```

It's used like a module in typescript

```
import * as my from './my'

my.property // returns 42
// my.property = doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a "little" late for this but using `typescript 4.8` you can do this:

```js
export module MyModule {
    export var myVariable: string = "test";
}
```

then use it like:

```js
MyModule.myVariable = "something else";
```